# Terraform: For each loop for multiple objects within a block in a resource

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to set up multiple autoscaling rules for an Azure App Service Plan using Terraform.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "autoscalingTest"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set" "example" {
  # ...
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting" "example" {
  name                = "myAutoscaleSetting"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  target_resource_id  = azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set.example.id

  profile {
    name = "defaultProfile"

    capacity {
      default = 1
      minimum = 1
      maximum = 10
    }

    rule {
      metric_trigger {
        metric_name        = "Percentage CPU"
        metric_resource_id = azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set.example.id
        time_grain         = "PT1M"
        statistic          = "Average"
        time_window        = "PT5M"
        time_aggregation   = "Average"
        operator           = "GreaterThan"
        threshold          = 75
        metric_namespace   = "microsoft.compute/virtualmachinescalesets"
        dimensions {
          name     = "AppName"
          operator = "Equals"
          values   = ["App1"]
        }
      }

      scale_action {
        direction = "Increase"
        type      = "ChangeCount"
        value     = "1"
        cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }

    rule {
      metric_trigger {
        metric_name        = "Percentage CPU"
        metric_resource_id = azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set.example.id
        time_grain         = "PT1M"
        statistic          = "Average"
        time_window        = "PT5M"
        time_aggregation   = "Average"
        operator           = "LessThan"
        threshold          = 25
      }

      scale_action {
        direction = "Decrease"
        type      = "ChangeCount"
        value     = "1"
        cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }
  }

  notification {
    email {
      send_to_subscription_administrator    = true
      send_to_subscription_co_administrator = true
      custom_emails                         = ["admin@contoso.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, I do not want to repeat the rules. So I will just define one block for the rules and use the variables file to set the values for the multiple rules.

This is what I have so far, but it's not working:

**main.tf file**

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting" "main" {
  name                = var.monitor_autoscale_setting_name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  target_resource_id  = var.target_resource_id
  enabled             = var.monitor_autoscale_setting_enabled

  profile {
    name = var.autoscale_profile_name

    capacity {
      default = var.profile_capacity_default
      minimum = var.profile_capacity_minimum
      maximum = var.profile_capacity_maximum
    }

    for_each = var.rules
    metric_trigger {
      metric_name        = each.value["metric_name"]
      metric_resource_id = each.value["metric_resource_id"]
      time_grain         = each.value["metric_time_grain"]
      statistic          = each.value["metric_statistic"]
      time_window        = each.value["metric_time_window"]
      time_aggregation   = each.value["metric_time_aggregation"]
      operator           = each.value["metric_operator"]
      threshold          = each.value["metric_threshold"]
    }

    scale_action {
      direction = each.value["scale_action_direction"]
      type      = each.value["scale_action_type"]
      value     = each.value["scale_action_value"]
      cooldown  = each.value["scale_action_cooldown"]
    }

  notification {
    email {
      send_to_subscription_administrator    = var.send_to_subscription_administrator
      send_to_subscription_co_administrator = var.send_to_subscription_co_administrator
      custom_emails                         = var.notification_custom_emails
    }
  }
}
```

**module file**

```
module "monitor_autoscale_setting" {
  source                            = "../../../modules/azure/monitor-autoscale-setting"
  monitor_autoscale_setting_name    = var.monitor_autoscale_setting_name
  resource_group_name               = var.resource_group_name
  resource_group_location           = var.resource_group_location
  target_resource_id                = var.app_service_plan_id
  monitor_autoscale_setting_enabled = var.monitor_autoscale_setting_enabled
  autoscale_profile_name            = var.autoscale_profile_name
  profile_capacity_default          = var.profile_capacity_default
  profile_capacity_minimum          = var.profile_capacity_minimum
  profile_capacity_maximum          = var.profile_capacity_maximum

  rules = {
    "rule1" = {
      metric_trigger = {
        metric_name             = var.metric_name
        metric_resource_id      = var.app_service_plan_id
        metric_time_grain       = var.metric_time_grain
        metric_statistic        = var.metric_statistic
        metric_time_window      = var.metric_time_window
        metric_time_aggregation = var.metric_time_aggregation
        metric_operator         = var.metric_operator
        metric_threshold        = var.metric_threshold
      }
      scale_action = {
        scale_action_direction = var.scale_action_direction
        scale_action_type      = var.scale_action_type
        scale_action_value     = var.scale_action_value
        scale_action_cooldown  = var.scale_action_cooldown
      }
    }
    "rule2" = {
      metric_name             = var.metric_name
      metric_resource_id      = var.app_service_plan_id
      metric_time_grain       = var.metric_time_grain
      metric_statistic        = var.metric_statistic
      metric_time_window      = var.metric_time_window
      metric_time_aggregation = var.metric_time_aggregation
      metric_operator         = var.metric_operator
      metric_threshold        = var.metric_threshold
      scale_action_direction  = var.scale_action_direction
      scale_action_type       = var.scale_action_type
      scale_action_value      = var.scale_action_value
      scale_action_cooldown   = var.scale_action_cooldown
    }
  }
}
```

**variables.tf file**

```
variable "rules" {
  type = map(object({
    metric_trigger = {
      metric_name             = string
      metric_time_grain       = string
      metric_statistic        = string
      metric_time_window      = string
      metric_time_aggregation = string
      metric_operator         = string
      metric_threshold        = number
    }
    scale_action = {
      scale_action_direction = string
      scale_action_type      = string
      scale_action_value     = string
      scale_action_cooldown  = string
    }
  }))
  default = {
    "rule1" = {
      metric_trigger = {
        metric_name             = "Percentage CPU"
        metric_time_grain       = "PT1M"
        metric_statistic        = "Average"
        metric_time_window      = "PT5M"
        metric_time_aggregation = "Average"
        metric_operator         = "GreaterThan"
        metric_threshold        = 90
      }
      scale_action = {
        scale_action_direction = "Increase"
        scale_action_type      = "ChangeCount"
        scale_action_value     = "1"
        scale_action_cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }
    "rule2" = {
      metric_trigger = {
        metric_name             = "Percentage CPU"
        metric_time_grain       = "PT1M"
        metric_statistic        = "Average"
        metric_time_window      = "PT5M"
        metric_time_aggregation = "Average"
        metric_operator         = "LessThan"
        metric_threshold        = 10
      }
      scale_action = {
        scale_action_direction = "Decrease"
        scale_action_type      = "ChangeCount"
        scale_action_value     = "1"
        scale_action_cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }
  }
}

variable "monitor_autoscale_setting_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the AutoScale Setting"
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the resource group in which to create the App Service Plan component"
}

variable "resource_group_location" {
  type        = string
  description = "The supported Azure location where the resource exists"
}

variable "target_resource_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "Specifies the resource ID of the resource that the autoscale setting should be added to"
}

variable "monitor_autoscale_setting_enabled" {
  type        = bool
  description = "Specifies whether automatic scaling is enabled for the target resource. Defaults to true"
}

variable "autoscale_profile_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the profile"
}

variable "profile_capacity_default" {
  type        = number
  description = "The number of instances that are available for scaling if metrics are not available for evaluation"
}

variable "profile_capacity_minimum" {
  type        = number
  description = "The minimum number of instances for this resource. Valid values are between 0 and 1000."
}

variable "profile_capacity_maximum" {
  type        = number
  description = "The maximum number of instances for this resource. Valid values are between 0 and 1000"
}
```

**Here are the errors**:

```
│ Error: Invalid type specification
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 162, in variable "rules":
│  162:     metric_trigger = {
│  163:       metric_name             = string
│  164:       metric_time_grain       = string
│  165:       metric_statistic        = string
│  166:       metric_time_window      = string
│  167:       metric_time_aggregation = string
│  168:       metric_operator         = string
│  169:       metric_threshold        = number
│  170:     }
│ 
│ A type specification is either a primitive type keyword (bool, number, string) or a complex type constructor call, like list(string).
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid type specification
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 171, in variable "rules":
│  171:     scale_action = {
│  172:       scale_action_direction = string
│  173:       scale_action_type      = string
│  174:       scale_action_value     = string
│  175:       scale_action_cooldown  = string
│  176:     }
│ 
│ A type specification is either a primitive type keyword (bool, number, string) or a complex type constructor call, like list(string).
```

Any form of help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is happening? Writing "it is not working" does not provide any information about your problem.

Comment: Are you sure you got the "levels" of the objects/maps right? Looks like perhaps you are referencing f.ex. "metric_name" at the wrong level; 
`for_each = var.rules` means that each.value is the `metric_trigger` and the `scale_action` objects, doesn't it? So you can't do `each.value["metric_name"]`, I think.

Comment: I have iterated over it multiple times and I keep running into different errors. If you could suggest a way that you think it can be done right, I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The correct type for your `var.rules` is as below (you forgot `object`):

```
variable "rules" {
  type = map(object({
    metric_trigger = object({
      metric_name             = string
      metric_time_grain       = string
      metric_statistic        = string
      metric_time_window      = string
      metric_time_aggregation = string
      metric_operator         = string
      metric_threshold        = number
    })
    scale_action = object({
      scale_action_direction = string
      scale_action_type      = string
      scale_action_value     = string
      scale_action_cooldown  = string
    })
  }))
  default = {
    "rule1" = {
      metric_trigger = {
        metric_name             = "Percentage CPU"
        metric_time_grain       = "PT1M"
        metric_statistic        = "Average"
        metric_time_window      = "PT5M"
        metric_time_aggregation = "Average"
        metric_operator         = "GreaterThan"
        metric_threshold        = 90
      }
      scale_action = {
        scale_action_direction = "Increase"
        scale_action_type      = "ChangeCount"
        scale_action_value     = "1"
        scale_action_cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }
    "rule2" = {
      metric_trigger = {
        metric_name             = "Percentage CPU"
        metric_time_grain       = "PT1M"
        metric_statistic        = "Average"
        metric_time_window      = "PT5M"
        metric_time_aggregation = "Average"
        metric_operator         = "LessThan"
        metric_threshold        = 10
      }
      scale_action = {
        scale_action_direction = "Decrease"
        scale_action_type      = "ChangeCount"
        scale_action_value     = "1"
        scale_action_cooldown  = "PT1M"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Marcin. I am running into an error `Error: Reference to undeclared input variable
│ 
│   on main.tf line 124, in module "monitor_autoscale_setting":
│  124:         metric_name             = var.metric_name
│ 
│ An input variable with the name "metric_name" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "metric_name" {} block.` This error also affects all other attributes in the block, as I'm getting the `An input variable with the name "metric_statistic" has not been declared. This variable can be declared with a variable "metric_statistic" {} block.`

Comment: @PromisePreston This is a new issue. The original error that you reported about `Invalid type specification` has been solved. If so, new question for the new problem should be made.

Comment: Thank you @Marcin, I already explained previously in the question what I'm trying to achieve. I have tried multiple solutions as well before I arrived at this one. Making this error go off doesn't really answer the question, that was why I did not want to include the errors in the question. All I want to achieve is to have more than one rule in the module dynamically, and I stated it in the question that I asked.

Comment: @PromisePreston I see. I think your question may be to complex if it has multiple errors, thus so far hasn't attracted any other answers. Maybe breaking it down to smaller questions which address individual issues/errors would be more beneficial.

Comment: @PromisePreston You are trying to reference a variable called `metric_name`. You have not declared such an input variable. What you have, is a a variable called `rules` which is a map of rules (and a rule is an object of objects) in which `metric_name` exists. (I.e. `metric_name` is "wrapped" inside an object inside another object in the `rules` map and cannot be referenced directly. `metric_name` is inside the `metric_trigger` object which is inside the `rule1` object in the `rules` map. (Ref. my comment on the original post. Hope this is somewhat clearer, I see that one might be confusing.)